# Default Save Directory in FPDF library

Tags: php, fpdf

I am currently developing php project using fpdf library, Is it possible to set a default directory for saving generated pdf files in php and mysql in fdpf library?

Answer (score 0):

Save PDF In a directory: 
[Check this thread](http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/43536-how-i-can-save-pdf-file.html) and you can
[check this as well](http://devmanuals.com/tutorials/php/save-pdf-in-folder.html)

And, we generally don't store(yes, there are exceptions!) files directly in Databases, we store the file path instead. So, MySQL only keeps the file-path of the PDF you stored in the directory.

Comment: when i save it the file name shows this C-xampphtdocsannapolisvetcareDocsAppointment it doesnt read the "\" nor "/" character note im using codeigniter here is the code      `$filename='Appointment.pdf';
  $this->ColoredTable($header, $data);
  $this->Footer();
  $this->fpdf->Output('C:\xampp\htdocs\annapolisvetcare\Docs'.$filename,'I');`

Comment: Please re-edit the question with this and explain a bit. Not very clear to me

Comment: For example i generate a pdf output on my browser, so i want it to save in my `C:/xampp/htdocs/annapolisvetcare/Docs` Directory.. but when i click the save button it displays in the filename bar before saving in windows is `C-_xampp_htdocs_annapolisvetcare_Docs` my "/"  in `$this->fpdf->Output('C:\xampp\htdocs\annapolisvetcare\Docs'.$filename,'I');` becomes "_" and the ":" becomes "-"

Comment: or if i write `C:\xampp\htdocs\annapolisvetcare\Docs\Appointment.pdf` it only shows like this `C-xampphtdocsannapolisvetcareDocsAppointment` in the save bar.